# How to get rows between lines?

Tags: text-processing, perl

I have a perl oneliner:

```
echo -e 'sla\ndfjAAAAk\nsaljdfla\nsjdfBBBBsadf\njasdf' | perl -E 'my $_ = do { local $/; <> }; say join qq!\n!, m!\QAAAA\E\K(.*?)(?=\QBBBB\E)!gs'
k
saljdfla
sjdf
```

it works, but I need this output:

```
dfjAAAAk
saljdfla
sjdfBBBBsadf
```

so I need the lines that contains "AAAA" and "BBBB" too - not just "from" and "to" them. How can I do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want the [range](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Range-Operators) operator.  You don't need to "slurp" your file either.

```
STR='sla\ndfjAAAAk\nsaljdfla\nsjdfBBBBsadf\njasdf' 
echo -e ${STR} | perl -nE 'm{^dfjAAAAk}..m{^sjdfBBBB} and print'
dfjAAAAk
saljdfla
sjdfBBBBsadf
```

Comment: +1. or `print if /AAAA/../BBBB/` is a little tidier IMO.

Comment: perl -nE 'print if /AAAA/../BBBB/' works :D

Comment: @gaskopeter TMTOWTDI